# Excel hangs/crashes while updating external link at file opening

Tags: excel, powerquery

I encountered this weird ass and funny error.

I built a file for data ETL. This one takes in various .csv files, combines them and export new .csv files using VBA. The file is originally named as "xxx Modelling ETL.xlsm". It could be opened normally till one day it hangs or crashes while trying to recalculating something (may be the underground query).

After hours of struggling, I opened the file as a copy (under a new name of Copy of ...). Strangely it ran smoothly, no crash or hang. Then I try rename it by remove the "Copy of" part, then the error occurs again.

I want to share this as there could be someone has the same problem, or someone who could shed some light on this black magic thing.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions:

- Rename the file or move it to local drive instead of Onedrive makes thing works normally again.
- Open Trust Center, disable Macro with notification, Trusted Locations, and Trusted Documents. Enable them for specific files when open, not for all.